# how to bias a random number generator

Tags: c++, random

i am using the random number generator provided with stl c++. how do we bias it so that it produces smaller random numbers with a greater probability than larger random numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in this case you probably would like a certain probability distribution. You can generate any distribution from a uniform random number generator, the question is only how it should look like. [Rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) is a common way of generating distributions that are hard to describe otherwise, but in your case something simpler might suffice.

You can take a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) for many common distribution functions. [Chi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution), [Chi-Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) and [Exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) look like good candidates.

Answer (score 8):

One simple way would be to take every random number generated in the range [0,1) and raise it to any power greater than 1, depending how skewed you want the results

Comment: Only problem is that this will skew the results toward the bigger numbers. Perhaps `1-x^n` or `x^n` with n below 1.

Comment: No, it won't; 0.5 ^ 1.4 ~== 0.38. So long as 0<x<1 and n>1, x^n < x

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::discrete_distribution` to calculate random numbers with a skewed probability distribution.  See example here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/discrete_distribution/